# Initialize 2d Array at compile and allow user input

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, multidimensional-array, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to declare an array that is sized at runtime/compile through an overload constructor.

```
private:
auto** arr = new int[n][n];


overloadConstruct(int n){
arr[n][n] = {0,0};
}
```

This does not work, it says the second n needs to be constant and auto is not allowed. Any help would be appreciated. I am not sure of all the rules with arrays, especially 2d arrays when doing this. I just need to be able to size a 2d array at runtime/compile through an input.

Comment: Run-time and compile-time are two distinct phases. Which one do you want to choose? And **runtime/compile-time** is not meaningful in your case. Please ask more clearly.

Comment: `auto` is not allowed for class members. Array sizes must be known at compile time in C++. gcc allows variable array lengths as an extension, but not in this context. Consider   using `vector` instead.

Comment: @digito_evo runtime is what I want

Comment: Check my answer then.

Answer (score 2):

Use a vector of vectors instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class Foo
{
public:
    Foo( const int rowCount, const int colCount )
    : m_2dArray( rowCount, std::vector<int>( colCount ) ) // initialize the vector
    {                                                     // member like this
    }

    void printArr() const
    {
        for ( size_t row = 0; row < m_2dArray.size( ); ++row )
        {
            for ( size_t col = 0; col < m_2dArray[ 0 ].size( ); ++col )
            {
                std::cout << m_2dArray[ row ][ col ] << " ";
            }

            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > m_2dArray; // the vector member
};


int main ()
{
    int rowCount { };
    int colCount { };

    std::cout << "Enter row count: ";
    std::cin >> rowCount;
    std::cout << "Enter column count: ";
    std::cin >> colCount;

    std::cout << "\nThe contents of 2D array:\n";

    Foo obj( rowCount, colCount ); // construct the object using user's input
    obj.printArr( );
}
```

The output:

```
Enter row count: 10
Enter column count: 20

The contents of 2D array:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

As you can see, the user can enter the values at **runtime**.